# How to import a Model from Controller in Flask api

Tags: python, flask, model

Im kinda new in api creations and  trying to make one in Flask from zero. I have a issue making the model. Here is the code.

**main.py :**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse #Reqparse sobra (?)
from controllers.attribute_controller import Attribute
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)



Attribute()
api.add_resource(Attribute, "/attribute/<int:attribute_id>")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**attribute_controller.py**

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
from models.attribute_model import AttibuteModel
attribute_put_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
attribute_put_args.add_argument("name", type=str, help="Name is required", required=True )

attributes = {}

class Attribute(Resource):

    def get(self, attribute_id):
        return attributes[attribute_id]
    
    def put(self, attribute_id):
        args = attribute_put_args.parse_args()
        attributes[attribute_id] = args
        return attributes[attribute_id],201
```

**attribute_model.py**

```
from main import db

class AttibuteModel(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):

        return f"Attribute(name={name})"
```

**test.py**

```
import requests

BASE = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

response = requests.put(BASE + "attribute/1", {"name": "red"})
print(response.json())
```

I got this error:

[image]

I know why i got the error, but i dont know any other solution to acced the model in my controllers.
I need the attribute_model in my attribute_controller to change it but i dont know how to solve the error. I've tried to follow this instructions:
[How to avoid circular imports in a Flask app with Flask SQLAlchemy models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718768/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-a-flask-app-with-flask-sqlalchemy-models)
But I didn't understand it at all so I don't know how to continue :(. Thx for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a circular import.

In `attribute_controller.py` you're importing `AttibuteModel` (missing an 'r' there by the way).

In `attribute_model.py` you're importing `db` from `main`.

In `main.py` you're importing `Attribute` from `attribute_controller.py` (which imports AttibuteModel which imports db) on line 3, before `db` has been created on line 11.

Move the import statement to after db initialisation:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from controllers.attribute_controller import Attribute
```

Comment: Still doesn't work... Same error:   File "E:\Usuario\Escritorio\newApi - Migglo\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from controllers.attribute_controller import Attribute
ImportError: cannot import name 'Attribute' from partially initialized module 'controllers.attribute_controller' (most likely due to a circular import) (E:\Usuario\Escritorio\newApi - Migglo\controllers\attribute_controller.py)

Comment: Thought that would work but apparently not... I can't tell exactly how to solve it since I don't have your code to mess around in, but there are lots of SO questions on circular import errors, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336802/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-python)