# Flask SQLALchemy: How to add initial data on init-db without circular imports?

Tags: python, flask

Flask SQLALchemy: How to add initial data on init-db without circular imports?
I have a flask app that as part of the initialization process it creates tables that are defined by flask-sqlalchemy models. I am trying to update the init-db command to add initial data on the newly created tables. However, this requires me to reference the same sqlalchemy models that import from the app file, thereby creating a circular import. I understand the problem but I am unable to see how I can work around this. I need the models to create the initial data for the tables, but the models require the db instance defined in the app file. both the app file and the model files are below:

`src/__init__.py`

```
import click

from flask import Flask
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase

from src.places.models import Place, Location


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)

def create_app(test_config=None):
    """Create and configure an instance of the Flask application."""
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    ...
    # initialize Flask-SQLAlchemy and the init-db command
    db.init_app(app)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)

    # apply the blueprints to the app
    ...

    return app

@click.command("init-db")
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    """Clear existing data and create new tables."""
    init_db()
    click.echo("Initialized the database.")

def init_db():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    add_initial_data()

def add_initial_data():
    home = Place("Home")
    db.session.add(home)

    home_loc = Location(...........)
    db.session.add(home_loc)

    db.session.flush()
    db.session.commit()
```

`src/models.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, Float, ForeignKey
from src import db


class Place(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "places"

    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(String(40), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "locations"

    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    place_id = db.Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Place.id))
    map_id = db.Column(String)
    latitude = db.Column(Float)
    longitude = db.Column(Float)
    address = db.Column(String(80))
```

Comment: Have you considered to create separate db file with just: 
`db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)`

Check [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718768/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-a-flask-app-with-flask-sqlalchemy-models?rq=2)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you just need to create a extension file to store all 3rd app such as db, kafka, mail,...

**src/extension.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Now, you use this `db` to import to file `models.py`, `__init__.py`